# Diagonally line-through in CSS

Tags: css, icons

I have a icon and I need to scratch it from top right corner to bottom left corner. It's any way to do it in CSS?

```
.sizebt {
    display:block;
    height:11px;
    border:1px solid #d9d9d9;
    background:#d1d1d1;
    color:#999;
    float:left;
    margin:0 6px 6px 0;
    text-align:center;
    padding:2px 6px;
    line-height:11px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.sizebt_sel {
    display:block;
    height:11px;
    border:1px solid #666666;
    background:#EEEEEE;
    float:left;
    margin:0 6px 6px 0;
    text-align:center;
    padding:2px 6px;
    line-height:11px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe you could try to add an After to your icon container like this:

```
.icon:after {
    content:" ";
    height:10px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    left:-30px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

and example: http://jsfiddle.net/o2yoh5LL/

Comment: additional : for responsive reason please set `px` to `em`

Answer (score 0):

how about using css3 transform?

```
.sizebt_sel:after{
    display:block;
    top:2px;
    left:3px;
    height:14px;
    content:" ";
    position:absolute;
    padding:2px 6px;
    border-left:1px solid red;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
 }
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hemnett6/)

Answer (score 0):

use code like.

```css
 div {
   border-top: 1px solid black;
 }
 .box {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   position: relative;
 }
 div#div2 {
   -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   margin: 39px 0px 0px -45px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   height: 67px;
   width: 142px;
 }
```

```html
<div>hi test</div>

<div class="box">

  this is test
  <div id="div2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>

  </div
```